# What does "彼は必ず成功するに違いない" mean?

Tags: meaning

The following sentence is taken from Routledge's frequency dictionary of Japanese:

> 彼は必ず成功するに違いない。

The translation goes as follows:

> He must always succeed.

Is this translation correct? I interpret this sentence as "He will certainly succeed" or "I'm sure he will succeed" or something along those lines. If Routledge's translation is correct, what am I misinterpreting?

Comment: You're correct, I'm not really sure how they came up with that.

Comment: Your translations are more natural.  "He must always succeed" would be correct if it means "It must be (such) that he always succeeds", since "it must be that case that" ≈ "certainly".

Comment: Not sure if this could be a reason, but we are taught that "must" sometimes translates to に違いない as in *He must be crazy* = 彼は頭がおかしいに違いない.